# Plot an histogram with y-axis as percentage (using FuncFormatter?)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of data in which the numbers are between 1000 and 20 000.

```
data = [1000, 1000, 5000, 3000, 4000, 16000, 2000]
```

When I plot a histogram using the `hist()` function, the y-axis represents the number of occurrences of the values within a bin. Instead of the number of occurrences, I would like to have the percentage of occurrences.

[image: Histogram of the data list above]

Code for the above plot:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,5))
ax.hist(data, bins = len(list(set(data))))
```

I've been looking at this [post](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_percent_demo.html) which describes an example using `FuncFormatter` but I can't figure out how to adapt it to my problem. Some help and guidance would be welcome :)

**EDIT:** Main issue with the `to_percent(y, position)` function used by the `FuncFormatter`. The y corresponds to one given value on the y-axis I guess. I need to divide this value by the total number of elements which I apparently can' t pass to the function...

**EDIT 2:** Current solution I dislike because of the use of a global variable:

```
def to_percent(y, position):
    # Ignore the passed in position. This has the effect of scaling the default
    # tick locations.
    global n

    s = str(round(100 * y / n, 3))
    print (y)

    # The percent symbol needs escaping in latex
    if matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] is True:
        return s + r'$\%$'
    else:
        return s + '%'

def plotting_hist(folder, output):
    global n

    data = list()
    # Do stuff to create data from folder

    n = len(data)
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,5))
    ax.hist(data, bins = len(list(set(data))), rwidth = 1)

    formatter = FuncFormatter(to_percent)
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

    plt.savefig("{}.png".format(output), dpi=500)
```

**EDIT 3:** Method with `density = True`

[image]

Actual desired output (method with global variable):

[image]

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Other answers seem utterly complicated. A histogram which shows the proportion instead of the absolute amount can easily produced by weighting the data with `1/n`, where `n` is the number of datapoints.

Then a [`PercentFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter) can be used to show the proportion (e.g. `0.45`) as percentage (`45%`).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

data = [1000, 1000, 5000, 3000, 4000, 16000, 2000]

plt.hist(data, weights=np.ones(len(data)) / len(data))

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here we see that three of the 7 values are in the first bin, i.e. 3/7=43%.

Comment: Hi, this looks good. However, the bar plots are not finishing exactly on the x-axis ticks but they are going a bit to the right each time. How can I make these be aligned?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit You don't align bars of a histogram. They are precisely at the bin edges. If you want to change the bin edges, use histogram's `bins` argument.

Comment: Thank you for your response but visually the bin edges are not aligned to the tick marks of the x-axis. Therefore, it gets even difficult to interpret what are the values related to each bin.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: You fix this by choosing the bin edges, such that they are at nice numbers and set the ticks to those numbers, not the inverse.

Comment: To remove dependency on numpy, one can replace `weights=np.ones(len(data)) / len(data)` with `weights = [1/len(data)] * len(data)`.

Comment: True, you don't need `numpy` for this, as suggested by Petr. Here a variant `[100/len(df.index)] * len(df.index)` that may be appropriate in some cases.

Answer (score 14):

Simply set density to true, the weights will be implicitly normalized.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

data = [1000, 1000, 5000, 3000, 4000, 16000, 2000]

plt.hist(data, density=True)

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Best answer IMO.

Comment: `density=True` does not give "the percentage of occurrences," as requested by the OP. Most users will not be looking for `density=True`( Google it to see why).

Comment: *"Google it to see why"* -> or just give the answer: It represents the percentage of the area under the curve (the sum of the areas of every bars is 1.0)

Answer (score 9):

I think the simplest way is to use seaborn which is a layer on matplotlib. Note that you can still use `plt.subplots()`, `figsize()`, `ax`, and `fig` to customize your plot.

```
import seaborn as sns
```

And using the following code:

```
sns.displot(data, stat='probability'))
```

Also, `sns.displot` has so many parameters that allow for very complex and informative graphs very easily. They can be found here: [displot Documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html)

Answer (score 8):

You can calculate the percentages yourself, then plot them as a bar chart. This requires you to use `numpy.histogram` (which matplotlib uses "under the hood" anyway). You can then adjust the y tick labels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,5))
data = [1000, 1000, 5000, 3000, 4000, 16000, 2000]

heights, bins = np.histogram(data, bins = len(list(set(data))))

percent = [i/sum(heights)*100 for i in heights]

ax.bar(bins[:-1], percent, width=2500, align="edge")
vals = ax.get_yticks()
ax.set_yticklabels(['%1.2f%%' %i for i in vals])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found yet an other way to do so. As you can see in other answers, `density=True` alone doesn't solve the problem, as it calculates the area under the curve in percentage. But that can easily be converted, just divide it by the width of the bars.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [1000, 1000, 5000, 3000, 4000, 16000, 2000]
bins=10

plt.hist(data, bins=bins, density=True)

bar_width = (max(data)-min(data))/bins # calculate width of a bar
ticks = plt.yticks()[0] # get ticks
tick_labels = ticks * bar_width # calculate labels for ticks
tick_labels = map(lambda f: f"{f:0.2}%",tick_labels) # format float to string
plt.yticks(ticks=ticks, labels=tick_labels) # set new labels

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, the solution `weights=np.ones(len(data)) / len(data)` may be a shorther and cleaner. This is just an other way and without numpy

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to avoid using `global`s in your example.

Just add `n` to function parameters:

```
def to_percent(y, position, n):
    s = str(round(100 * y / n, 3))

    if matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex']:
        return s + r'$\%$'

    return s + '%'
```

and then create a partial function of two arguments that you can pass to `FuncFormatter`:

```
percent_formatter = partial(to_percent,
                            n=len(data))
formatter = FuncFormatter(percent_formatter)
```

---

Full code:

```
from functools import partial

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

data = [1000, 1000, 5000, 3000, 4000, 16000, 2000]


def to_percent(y, position, n):
    s = str(round(100 * y / n, 3))

    if matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex']:
        return s + r'$\%$'

    return s + '%'


def plotting_hist(data):    
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
    ax.hist(data, 
            bins=len(set(data)), 
            rwidth=1)

    percent_formatter = partial(to_percent,
                                n=len(data))
    formatter = FuncFormatter(percent_formatter)
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

    plt.show()


plotting_hist(data)
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Could you explain why this output is incorrect and the one from DavidG is correct? I really don't see the difference. They also don't have 43% in the first bin.

Comment: Sorry, it seems correct. But I don't think it's useful to have arbitrarily complicated numbers on the axes, like 42.857 instead of 40.

Comment: Both of yours are correct, but the one from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is simpler.