# Unable to plot histogram with time on x-axis using Matplotlib and Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot the number of times a user tweeted at specific times of the day. I plan to plot these on a histogram/bar chart with 24 "bins" - one for each hour.

I have the data in a Pandas dataframe in two columns - the tweet and the time of the tweet (as a datetime object).

I have converted the Time column into a Pandas time, however I am having a hard time plotting correctly. If I set the value of bins to be 24, then I get the following chart ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RsWp.jpg)) which doesn't look correct. Firstly the chart looks wrong, but secondly the x-axis has horrible formatting.

I would like to try to resolve these two issues. Firstly the data isn't being plotted correctly and secondly the horizontal axis formatting is incorrect.

I have plotted the data using Google Sheets and the correct chart should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lroL3.jpg). I don't mind if the values are % of total or absolute volume.

Code to generate plots can be found here. [generate_data.py](https://pastebin.com/E9NS2Uug) and [plot_data.py](https://pastebin.com/L9PXXhCQ)

Any help is hugely appreciated.

***plot_data.py***

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random

import generate_data


screen_name = "@joebiden"
data = generate_data.get_data(screen_name, save_output=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Time"]= pd.to_datetime(data["Time"], format="%H:%M") 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
bin_list = [datetime.time(x) for x in range(24)]

ax.hist(df["Time"], bins=24, color='lightblue')
plt.show()
```

***generate_data.py***

```
import json
import re
from datetime import datetime

import tweepy

import common_words
import twitter_auth 



def create_connection():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitter_auth.CONSUMER_KEY, twitter_auth.CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(twitter_auth.ACCESS_KEY, twitter_auth.ACCESS_SECRET)
    return tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)


def retrieve_next_set_of_tweets(screen_name, api, count,max_id):
    '''Return next 200 user tweets'''
    return api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name,count=count, tweet_mode='extended', max_id=max_id)


def get_tweet_times(screen_name, api):
    user_tweet_count = api.get_user(screen_name).statuses_count

    all_tweets = {'Tweet':[], 'Time':[]}
    block_of_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name,count=200, tweet_mode='extended')
    all_tweets["Tweet"].extend([tweet.full_text for tweet in block_of_tweets])
    all_tweets["Time"].extend([tweet.created_at for tweet in block_of_tweets])
    oldest = block_of_tweets[-1].id - 1

    
    while block_of_tweets:    
        try:
            block_of_tweets = retrieve_next_set_of_tweets(screen_name, api, 200, oldest)
            oldest = block_of_tweets[-1].id - 1
        except IndexError: #Reached limit of 3245
            pass
        # all_tweets.update({tweet.full_text: tweet.created_at.time() for tweet in block_of_tweets}) 
        all_tweets["Tweet"].extend([tweet.full_text for tweet in block_of_tweets])
        all_tweets["Time"].extend([tweet.created_at for tweet in block_of_tweets])
 
    return all_tweets


def get_all_tweets(screen_name, api):
    user_tweet_count = api.get_user(screen_name).statuses_count

    all_tweets = []
    block_of_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name,count=200, tweet_mode='extended')
    all_tweets.extend([tweet.full_text for tweet in block_of_tweets])
    oldest = block_of_tweets[-1].id - 1
    

    while block_of_tweets:    
        try:
            block_of_tweets = retrieve_next_set_of_tweets(screen_name, api, 200, oldest)
            oldest = block_of_tweets[-1].id - 1
        except IndexError: #Reached limit of 3245
            pass

        all_tweets.extend([tweet.full_text for tweet in block_of_tweets]) 
    return all_tweets


def parse_all_tweets(tweet_list, max_words_to_show=50):
    tweet_dict = {}
    regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]')
    for tweet in tweet_list: 
        text = regex.sub("", tweet).lower().strip().split()
        
        for word in text:
            if word in common_words.MOST_COMMON_ENGLISH_WORDS: continue
            if word in tweet_dict.keys():
                tweet_dict[word] += 1
            else:
                if len(tweet_dict.items()) == max_words_to_show:
                    return tweet_dict
                tweet_dict[word] = 1
    return tweet_dict
    
    
def get_data(screen_name, words_or_times="t", save_output=False):
    api = create_connection()
    print(f"...Getting max of 3245 tweets for {screen_name}...")

    if words_or_times == "t":
        all_tweets = get_tweet_times(screen_name, api)
        suffix = "tweet_times"
        
    elif words_or_times == "w":
        suffix = "ranked_words"
        parsed_tweets = parse_all_tweets(get_all_tweets(screen_name, api))
        parsed_tweets = {k:v for k,v in sorted(parsed_tweets.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

    else:
        return "...Error. Please enter 't' or 'w' to signify 'times' or 'words'."

    if save_output:
        f_name = f"{screen_name}_{suffix}.json"
        with open(f_name, "w") as f:
            json.dump(all_tweets if words_or_times == "t" else parsed_tweets, f, indent=4, default=str)
        
        print(f"...Complete! File saved as '{f_name}'")

    return all_tweets if words_or_times == "t" else parsed_tweets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_data(screen_name="@joebiden", save_output=True)
```

Comment: Can you give a few rows of ```df = pd.DataFrame(data)```? Also, check you indeed have dates.

Comment: Here are the first 5 rows of the df.
0  RT @Transition46: We stand together as one Ame... 2020-11-08 14:28:23
1  From the bottom of my heart: thank you. https:... 2020-11-08 02:20:00
2  A nation united.\n\nA nation strengthened.\n\n... 2020-11-08 02:10:00
3  With full hearts and steady hands, with faith ... 2020-11-08 02:08:00
4  Tonight, the whole world is watching America. ... 2020-11-08 02:05:00```

Comment: When I output the first 5 records of df["Time"] I get the following. They are are <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> but still show the date and time, even though I try to format them to time only on line 14 of plot_data.py. 0   2020-11-08 14:28:23
1   2020-11-08 02:20:00
2   2020-11-08 02:10:00
3   2020-11-08 02:08:00
4   2020-11-08 02:05:00

Answer (score 0):

OK. So you want to have time only from your date time. Try replacing

```
df["Time"]= pd.to_datetime(data["Time"], format="%H:%M")
```

With

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format= '%H:%M' ).dt.time
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That has formatted the times correctly e.g. `14:28:23, 02:20:00,02:10:00` e.t.c. However now I get an error when trying to plot these. The error I get is `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'float'` when the script tries to run `ax.hist(df["Time"], bins=23, color='lightblue')`

Comment: Do you have missing values in your dataset? Check that. If so, treat them before doing anything else.

Comment: Doesn't look like there are data missing. I've dumped the CSV into Google Sheets and published that as a webpage [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTc97VEzlfDP_jEkjC7dTbJzcLBLDQeFwPMg6E36BaiH5qkhnedSz8wsVGUMyW6kt85rD20BcTMbvqp/pubhtml) and there doesn't appear to be any rows where either column has a missing value.

Comment: I have temporarily dropped all but the first 10 records, and getting the same error when trying to plot those `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'float'`, even though there are definitely no data missing - https://imgur.com/a/ztABgZf

Answer (score 0):

I have tried plotting the [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTc97VEzlfDP_jEkjC7dTbJzcLBLDQeFwPMg6E36BaiH5qkhnedSz8wsVGUMyW6kt85rD20BcTMbvqp/pubhtml) you have shared in the comment to the answer by Serge de Gosson de Varennes. The only thing I needed to change in your `plot_data.py` script was the date `format` where I added seconds. The rest worked as expected, the times are processed correctly for the x-axis.

Here is an example where the histogram is created with [`pd.Series.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.hist.html) for convenience. The `weights` argument is included to produce a graph with percentages. Most of the code is for formatting:

```
import numpy as np                 # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd                # v 1.1.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # v 3.3.2
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Import data from html table into pandas dataframe
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTc97VEzlfDP_jEkjC7dTbJzcLBLDQeFwPMg6E36BaiH5qkhnedSz8wsVGUMyW6kt85rD20BcTMbvqp/pubhtml'
table, = pd.read_html(url, header=[1], index_col=1)
df = table.iloc[:, 1:]

# Save time variable as a pandas series of datetime dtype
time_var = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')

# Plot variable with pandas histogram function
ax = time_var.hist(bins=24, figsize=(10,5), grid=False, edgecolor='white', zorder=2,
                   weights=np.ones(time_var.size)/time_var.size)

# Format x and y-axes tick labels
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.1%}')

# Additional formatting
alpha = 0.3
ax.grid(axis='y', zorder=1, color='black', alpha=alpha)
for spine in ['top', 'right', 'left']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_alpha(alpha)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', color=[0, 0, 0, alpha])
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', length=0)
ax.set_title('Tweets sent per hour of day in UTC', fontsize=14, pad=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Relative frequency (% of total)', size=12, labelpad=10)

plt.show()
```

[image: tweets_per_hour]

Because the counts are spread over 24 hours in this histogram, you may notice that the height of the bars are slightly different from those in the histogram in the image you have shared as a reference where the counts seem to be grouped into 23 bins instead of 24.

---

Reference: [this answer by ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51477080/14148248)