# How to show percentage instead of count on my Seaborn displot y axis?

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram

I have the following code: 
`sns.displot(data_df_cleaned, x='estimate_error', bins = [-30, -5, 5, 30, 80])`
which plots the following simple histogram, but I want my **y axis** to report **percentage**. It is important that I do this with Seaborn, for which I couldn't find any answer in the documentation or stackoverflow.

[image]

Comment: The easy way is to divide the data by the max value / 100.

Comment: @TimRoberts tnx. What about the hard way?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You seem to be asking someone to teach you how to compute percentages.  This is an easy look-up, not a SO question.

Comment: @Prune Tnx for your downvote. However, I'm not looking for "manually" calculating percentages. I'm asking for a parametric way, which I found. Displot takes kind='hist' as default, and if a parameter from histplot called stat is set such that stat='probability', the y axis shows percentage instead of count.

Comment: Excellent -- even thought the actual need wasn't in the place I expected.  Still, it's straightforward research -- which you do before you post here.

Comment: please check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473993/plot-an-histogram-with-y-axis-as-percentage-using-funcformatter

Comment: @Tyr Thanks. The answers were really painful because I already solved my problem using the stat parameter in the Seaborn's displot. I posted my solution as an answer here

Answer (score 2):

`sns.Displot` takes `kind='hist'` as default, and if a parameter from `sns.histplot` called `stat` is set such that `stat='probability'`, the y axis shows percentage instead of count. So the answer is:

```
sns.displot(data_df_cleaned, x='estimate_error', bins = [-30, -5, 5, 30, 80], stat='probability')
```