How to check if my spectrum has one symmetrical peak, that is, Gaussian
For example, there are 2 spectra:
Spectrum 15 has a peak which is near-symmetrical, and has a near-Gaussian shape, so that it is a signal
Spectrum 371 has no peak at all and should be treated as noise
I know I can make a Gaussian fit to every spectrum and check if the error is small, but I have ~1000 spectra to check and this method is very slow
Is there any summary statistics that I can calculate and tell a spectrum if it has a peak signal (it will appear at any velocity) or noise
for example signal is k>0, noise is k<0


spectra data: (13 True and 2 False signals)
x: https://pastebin.com/2rAByJ1w
y: https://pastebin.com/RfRvAh18

Low-pass filter it and look for a peak?

If you have a known characteristic peak shape then a matched filter correlation will give you the most accurate position and amplitude of the peak. BTW That peak isn't vey Gaussian or symmetric it is more triangular with a high tail. Otherwise as @lastchance has already suggested the quickest method is a fairly brutal low pass filter and then look for a peak. Your peaks are significantly oversampled if that graph is typical of their FWHM.

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

You already had the right idea for checking if the data fits well to a given curve, but it can be done very efficiently. Using matched filters a run time of <100 microseconds on a graph with 512 points is attainable. The solution I present here has an approx 98% accuracy in identifying the signal and fails when the signal is very narrow (in this case when its less than about 5 samples) or very wide (in this case when it occupies most of the window). If this is common, the matched filter can be adjusted to compensate.
Approach:

Generate the filter you want to match to in the data. In this case, I used a Gaussian density function.
Trim the input data to get rid of those strange values at the start
Use numpy.convolve to apply a matched filter
Use scipy.signal.find_peaks to identify where the peak responses are
Choose the highest peak
Check if that peak is above some threshold

This approach has the bonus benefit that it also tells you where that peak occurred with high accuracy (typically <1% error).
Here is a sample implementation:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy


def get_normal_density_fun(x_data: np.ndarray, center: float = 0.0, std: float = 1.0, amp: float = 1.0):
    # https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143633
    return amp / (0.4 / std) * (1 / (std * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))) * np.exp(-((x_data - center) ** 2) / (2 * std ** 2))


def make_data(n: int, peak_location: float | None, rng: np.random._generator.Generator = None) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    # This function is an attempt to recreate the data shown in your graph upload, not required during typical use
    NOISE_ABS = 0.1
    MAX_CENTER = 1.0
    X_MIN = 100
    X_MAX = 190
    INIT_SLOPE_END_X = 115
    INIT_SLOPE_END_Y = -0.05

    if rng is None:
        rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

    slope_end_index = int(n / (X_MAX - X_MIN) * (INIT_SLOPE_END_X - X_MIN))
    slope_start_val = rng.random() * 0.8 + 0.2

    out_data_x = np.linspace(X_MIN, X_MAX, n)
    out_data = rng.random(size=(n,)) * NOISE_ABS

    out_data[:slope_end_index] += np.linspace(start=slope_start_val, stop=INIT_SLOPE_END_Y, num=slope_end_index)
    if peak_location is not None:
        std = (peak_location - INIT_SLOPE_END_X) * rng.random()
        amp = MAX_CENTER * (0.25 + 0.75 * rng.random())
        out_data += get_normal_density_fun(out_data_x, peak_location, std, amp)
    return out_data_x, out_data


def find_response(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, plot_all: bool = False):
    # This is the filter we are trying to match the signal filter to
    #   Adjust std and amp to fit
    filter = get_normal_density_fun(np.linspace(-15, 15, 50), std=8, amp=5.0)
    y_trimmed = y.copy()
    # Due to some strange values at the beginning, 0 out the beginning
    y_trimmed[:len(y) // 8] = 0.0
    # https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/94212
    matched_filter_output = np.convolve(y_trimmed, np.flip(filter), mode='same')
    # Use scipy to find all the peaks in the filter response
    peaks, properties = scipy.signal.find_peaks(matched_filter_output)
    # This block is for testing purposes, to understand how the system is working
    if plot_all:
        def scale(vec: np.ndarray, min_val: float = 0.0, max_val: float = 1.0, ref_vec: np.ndarray = None):
            if ref_vec is None:
                ref_vec = vec
            return (vec - np.min(ref_vec)) / (np.max(ref_vec) - np.min(ref_vec)) * (max_val - min_val) + min_val

        plt.plot(x, scale(matched_filter_output), label='filter response')
        plt.plot(x, scale(y), label='orig data')
        plt.plot(x, scale(y_trimmed, ref_vec=y), label='trimmed data')
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
    # Capture the prominence of each peak (how much does the peak stick up)
    prominences, _, _ = scipy.signal.peak_prominences(matched_filter_output, peaks)
    # Find the maximum prominence (which hopefully matches our signal)
    max_prom_index = np.argmax(prominences)
    # Find the x-value that the peak occurred at
    main_peak = peaks[max_prom_index]
    return x[main_peak], prominences[max_prom_index]


def _main():
    import sklearn.metrics
    import time
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)

    n = 512
    tests = 2 ** 10
    peak_truth = []
    peak_pred = []
    peak_error = []
    peak_error_percent = []
    tot_time = 0.0
    show_mismatches = False
    for has in [True, False]:
        first_run = True
        for i in range(tests // 2):
            if has:
                peak = rng.random() * 50 + 120
            else:
                peak = None
            x, y = make_data(n, peak, rng)
            if first_run:
                first_run = False
                find_response(x, y, True)
            tot_time -= time.perf_counter()
            xprom, prom = find_response(x, y)
            has_guess = prom > 30
            tot_time += time.perf_counter()

            # print(f'{peak if has else 0.0:8.1f} - {xprom:8.1f} : {prom:8.5f}')
            peak_truth.append(has)
            peak_pred.append(has_guess)
            if has:
                peak_error.append(xprom - peak)
                peak_error_percent.append((xprom - peak) / peak * 100)
            if show_mismatches and not has_guess == has:
                plt.plot(x, y)
                plt.show()
    print(f'Run time / prediction: {tot_time / tests * 1000:.2f} ms')
    total_correct = np.sum(np.array(peak_truth) == np.array(peak_pred))
    total_wrong = np.sum(np.array(peak_truth) != np.array(peak_pred))
    print(f'Correct / Wrong (%)  : {total_correct} / {total_wrong} ({total_correct / len(peak_truth) * 100:.1f}%)')
    print(f'Mean error (%)       : {np.mean(np.abs(peak_error)):.2f} ({np.mean(np.abs(peak_error_percent)):.2f}%)')
    print(f'Max / min error      : {np.max(np.abs(peak_error)):.2f} / {np.min(np.abs(peak_error)):.2f}')
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/51477080
    plt.hist(peak_error, bins=100, weights=np.ones(len(peak_error)) / len(peak_error) * 100)
    plt.xlabel('Error'); plt.ylabel('% of occurrances'); plt.title('Absolute Error')
    plt.show()
    cm = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(peak_truth, peak_pred).astype(float)
    for row in range(cm.shape[0]):
        cm[row] /= np.round(np.sum(cm[row]),3)
    disp = sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm * 100)
    disp.plot()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()

Which yields the following console:
Run time / prediction: 0.05 ms
Correct / Wrong (%)  : 1004 / 20 (98.0%)
Mean error (%)       : 0.77 (0.50%)
Max / min error      : 49.64 / 0.00

And the following plots where the first and second should be similar to your first and second from the question respectively:




In this example with the values that I used, it correctly predicted no signal every time, and predicted the presence of a signal 96% of the time.
In your use, you would adjust the values on the filter = get_normal_density_fun( ... line to match your data, those values match the toy data I generated. You may also need to adjust the line has_guess = prom > 30 to a number that matches your values. The commented out print line in that testing block shows the prominences, so you can run that on your actual data to see what values are typical and tune it that way.
Your typical use case for this function would probably be something along the lines of:
for fname in filelist:
    filedatax, filedatay = loadfile(fname)
    xprom, prom = find_response(filedatax, filedatay)
    if prom > 30:
        process_signal(filedatax, filedatay, xprom)

Let me know if you have any questions!

EDIT:
Using the data provided in the edit with pastebin (which I can't append due to size), it yields the following results, the first 13 have a signal, the last 2 do not, which is still pretty easy to identify. This was generated without modifying the code in anyway, so the matched filter values and threshold work as-is.
158.5 39.3
151.7 44.3
138.4 62.1
145.3 42.3
146.5 42.9
120.7 46.7
136.8 46.3
128.3 70.8
133.8 41.7
121.9 60.6
129.6 43.8
125.5 38.7
113.9 34.6
105.0 25.5
103.2 10.6


References:

Convolution: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/94212
Gaussian density function: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143633


Why (0.4 / std) * (1 / (std * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))), it should always return 1 (or σ√2π / σ√2π)

It seems that the np.convolve can also use from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter  and filter_sp = gaussian_filter(spectrum, sigma=sig)

@Firestar-Reimu Any source for the shape of the filter will do, and I encourage you to experiment a bit to find one that works well for your input data. The one that I showed above is very well tuned to the sample data I generated, which may not be all that accurate for your data, though I suspect it will work decently as-is. Did you have a chance to try it out?

I tried with my own data and find that scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter can work very well (and I don't need to set parameters) comparing to the customize filter here, I have tried some amp, std pairs and it is no better than scipy's

@Firestar-Reimu Awesome, I'm glad to hear that it worked!

The data sample is added in the question. I think your filter is more able to exagerrate the peak instead of fitting it. Also, as the filter is symmetrical, it seems to be no need of numpy.trim()?

@Firestar-Reimu I tested it on the data set you posted exactly as shown in the typical use case box and it worked perfectly for every data point you provided. Every sample which had a signal (all but the last by visual id) had a prom over 30 except one at 25 (25.5 - 70.8) and the one that did not have a signal had a prom of 10.6, making it easy to isolate still. Every estimated peak was spot on, within 1 or 2 of what I picked by hand visually. No alterations are necessary except maybe moving that threshold to 20 instead of 30.

@Firestar-Reimu Regarding the exaggeration of the peak, I am not sure what you are referring to, I do not apply any filters to the input data except to zero out that opening segment. Regarding the numpy.trim() question, I did not use that function nor did I apply any filters/alterations to the matched filter. Can you help me understand what you are referring to?

@Firestar-Reimu I originally missed your comment that the last 2 were no signal, which means the code as provided worked perfectly for every case you provided, the next lowest prominence was 34.6, making 30 still an ideal threshold.
